# Matrix Factorization problem (A = L*D*U)

Tags: matrices

I am having difficulty understanding the following question:

> Let L = [1 0 0 0;-2 1 0 0;-8 3 1 0; 6 -2 1 1],
>
> U = [4 2 -5 1;0 4 -1 9; 0 0 6 -1;0 0 0 5 ],
>
> A = L*U
>
> Write A as the product L*D*U where D is diagonal and U is a unit upper
>   triangular matrix. Show how it is related to U.

Is this a simple matrix multiplication problem? If so, what am I supposed to make up a triangular matrix (zero determinant matrix) and solve for `A`? . I don't understand what is implied by `A = L*U` when the question is telling me to write A as the product of L*U*D!

I am not looking for the solution. I am merely looking for the proper procedure I need to follow in order to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a matrix factorization problem, I believe, from the information given.

Comment: any help on how to solve the problem though?

Answer (score 1):

We're given
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -8 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 6 & -2 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 & -5 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & -1 & 9 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
and the task is to write $A$ as the product $LDU$, where $U$ is **unit** upper triangular (i.e., $1$s on the main diagonal).

To achieve this, we can apply row operations to the original $U$ to convert it to unit upper triangular (divide the 1st row by $4$, and so on).  Now we need to choose $D$ so that it "undoes" the row operations we just did.

Comment: I got the following for U:
`[1 1/2 -5/4 1/4; 0 1 -1/4  9/4; 0 0 1 1/6; 0 0 0 1]`
How do I figure out D from here?

Comment: $L$ remains the same; it's $D$ that needs to be chosen, and chosen such that $DU_{\text{new}}=U_{\text{old}}$.

Comment: My bad. I intended to write `D.` Is there a mathematical approach to finding D? I'm sure there is. I just can't seem to find any good resources online

Comment: The way I see it, is we apply the row operations $R_1 \gets \tfrac{1}{4} R_1$, $R_2 \gets \tfrac{1}{4} R_2$, $R_3 \gets \tfrac{1}{6} R_3$, $R_4 \gets \tfrac{1}{5} R_4$ to get $U_{\text{new}}$, so we obtain $D$ by applying the opposite row operations to $I$.